# Using batch request when insert columns in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, batch-request

I'm trying to insert a large number of columns into a table, I need to insert through 2 columns, now my code looks like this

```
sheet.insertColumnAfter(16),sheet.insertColumnAfter(18),sheet.insertColumnAfter(20),sheet.insertColumnAfter(22)
```

I tried to use an array, nothing worked, I will be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to insert the columns like `insertColumnAfter(16)`, `insertColumnAfter(18)`, `insertColumnAfter(20)` and `insertColumnAfter(22)` using Google Apps Script.
- When your goal is achieved, the inserted columns are the columns "Q", "T", "W" and "Z".
- You want to achieve this using an array.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, how about inserting the columns from `insertColumnAfter(22)` to `insertColumnAfter(16)`?

  - I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- In order to use the array, prepare an array including the column numbers, and using the array, the columns are inserted.

When above points are reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const columns = [16, 18, 20, 22];
columns.reverse().forEach(c => sheet.insertColumnAfter(c));
```

- In this script, the active sheet is used. So please modify it for your actual situation.
- When this script is run, the columns are inserted from the column 22 to the column 16. By this, the inserted columns are the columns "Q", "T", "W" and "Z".

#### References:

- [insertColumnAfter(afterPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertColumnAfter(Integer))
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Comment: @Tanakie Can you please tell me, I also have a formula that needs to be inserted into row 4 of each inserted column, the formula looks like this `=ArrayFormula(IFS($N$4:$N=0,"нет закупочной цены",P4:P=0,"нет цены магазина",$N$4:$N*P4:P>0,(P4:P-$N$4:$N)/$N$4:$N))`In this formula, will change only this range `P4:P`, I hope I described everything correctly

Comment: How can I insert it without going to the sheet every time? Tried through `RangeList` , But there is only `setValue`. Here is a link to sample [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14IAtU-31vZ4kU97nOupAmZ9hno5kp4nwGT_0GEFWfVA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Антон Кожевников Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. I apologize for this. So can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Right now I am using the following method to insert a formula, `var rr1 = sheet.getRange('Q4')   rr1.setValue('=ArrayFormula(IFS($N$4:$N=0,"нет закупочной цены",P4:P=0,"нет цены магазина",$N$4:$N*P4:P>0,(P4:P-$N$4:$N)/$N$4:$N))')` but it is very expensive, and so for each column

Comment: @Антон Кожевников Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your new question. But I would like to try to understand it. So can you give me a time to understand it? But if you are required to obtain the solution of your new question immediately, please tell me. At that time, I would like to recommend to post it as new question. By this, other users can think of your issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?